# Creating a button that shows a modal in AngularJS using UIBootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-click

On my html page (rollup.html), I have a button..

```
<li style="float: right;">
<button id="myBtn" ng-click="printDivModal('rollup-tab')">Modal Test</button>
</li>
```

and I want this button to show a modal.
In Rollup.js I have declared the scope.

```
$scope.printDivModal = function(divName) {
        console.log('opening pop up');
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'app/views/modals/stackedModal.html',
            size: 'sm',
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.name = 'top';  
              }
        });
    }
```

I have also declared the uibModal in the app controller

```
app.controller('Rollup', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $uibModal, headersvc, locFiltersvc) {
```

I get an error in the console when I click the Modal Test button
It says:

```
ReferenceError: '$modal' is undefined
at $scope.printDivModal (/rollup.js)
```

Can anyone help with this issue?  Thanks

EDIT:Here is the code for the modal I am trying to get to appear (stackedModal.html)

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You did not provide all dependencies for controller in you controller definition

Comment: @epitka what did I not provide in the controller definition?  I thought I did by declaring the uibModal.

Comment: where is "printDivModal" defined?

Comment: @alphapilgrim didn't I define it in rollup.html and implement in rollup.js.  I apologize I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
app.controller('Rollup', rollUpCtrl);

rollUpCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$uibModal','headersvc','locFiltersvc']

function rollUpCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $http, $uibModal, headersvc, locFiltersvc) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

you try this

```
app.controller('Rollup',['$scope','$rootScope','$http','$uibModal','headersvc','locFiltersvc', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $uibModal, headersvc, locFiltersvc){


}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the modal was not appearing due a few lines of code:

```
$scope.printDivModal = function(divName) {
        console.log('opening pop up');
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            //animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'app/views/modals/stackedModal.html',
            size: 'sm',
                /*controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.name = 'top';  
                  }
                */
            });
        }
```

I also decided to give the modal its own controller within its own js file, instead of defining it in the main js file.